# 13.04 WebApps Not Working

Tags: unity, 13.04, chromium, webapps

Just installed Chromium and unity-chromium-extension.
Now after a reboot, I get the option from GMail to install the WebApp.
I accept, however from then on nothing happens - a search for GMail in the dash gives nothing and there is nothing new in the messaging indicator.

Perhaps I am experiencing a bug, but I'd like to be sure that I am not overlooking anything before I come to that. So please give me a hand with this, it's my first time actually looking into this feature.

Cheers!

Comment: Post the contents of the webapps .desktop file (after stripping out lines relating to other languages).

Answer (score 1):

try to delete this folder
/home/yourusername/.config/chromium

> rm -R /home/yourusername/.config/chromium

Then restart your browser and see if it works.

Comment: No luck, the problem persists, but thanks for the help.

Comment: As a friendly gesture, it's nice to tell people to back up stuff first before running `rm`. Also, both Chrome and Chromium have a feature of adding a new user: look near the bottom of the page in `chrome://settings/`. So, stuff can be tested with a "new" and clean profile to determine whether there was indeed something wrong in the old profile. IMO, completely wiping one's profile by deleting `/home/yourusername/.config/chromium` is mostly not necessary.

Comment: Don't worry about it in this case as I had the sense to do so. Though you are right that it would perhaps be better to keep that in mind in the future.